# Chrome "bleaches" screenshots

Tags: windows, google-chrome, snipping-tool

Every once in a while as soon as I press Win+S to start the Snipping Tool, Chrome takes on a "bleached" pallor. This only affects Chrome and it happens on all four of my monitors. Restarting Chrome nor the computer has any effect. The effect extends to entire Chrome Window, not just the webpage content. The effect does not happen when I use Chrome's built-in screenshot tool.

This computer runs Windows 11 but I had the same problem on Windows 10 on another computer. This Windows 11 was upgraded from that copy of Windows 10.

Por ejemplo
[image]

Comment: Does this happen on other browsers? Is the effect consistent across multiple web sites?

Comment: @music2myear it only happens in Chrome on all websites.

Answer (score 0):

On the advice of a coworker I tried messing with this Chrome flag, `chrome://flags/#force-color-profile`, and found that the setting *HDR10 (HDR where available)* reliably caused the problem. However, when I initially had the problem the setting was on *Default*. When I return the setting back to *Default* the problem does not return.

I suspect that when *Default* is selected the color profile varies and sometimes settles on HDR10, probably when there's HDR content on a page, and then the problem starts.